# Finding nearest point in an array that is not equal to given point

Tags: python, scipy, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I have a point and an array of values. I wish to find the closest point y in the array such that x != y. Currently I am using the standard Scipy KDTree approach in Python, but this does not consider only unique points. Is there any workaround to this or does it require a manual implementation? Thanks!

Comment: You could try searching for further neighbors beyond the nearest one if they are not far enough away from the original to be unique. You can adjust the `leafsize` argument if duplicates are frequent enough to cause problems, as I assume you do not want to use brute-forcing if possible. The optimal value of `leafsize` and `k` (for the `.query()` method) depends on your data, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2D ARRAY SOLUTION**:
I recycled most of the same method as before but this time it ought to work for your structure

```
import math

X = [0,0] # Your cooridinate
x1 = X[0]
y1= X[1]

array = [[1,1],[0,1],[1,0],[-2,2]] # Sample array of data
smallestDistance = 9999 # Make it big so it can be replaced immediately, essentially just a placeholder

for point in array:
    x2 = point[0]
    y2 = point[1]
    separation = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1) #Distance equation in easy format
    if separation < smallestDistance and separation!=0:  # Could make this <= instead of < if you want to replace any ties for closest point
        smallestDistance = separation
        closestPoint = point
print(f"Nearest cooridinate = {closestPoint}, separation from {X} is: {smallestDistance}")
```

**OLD SOLUTION FOR 1D ARRAY**:
I'm not too sure what the structure of your array is, but from what I can tell you've got a 1d array and a given value within in; you want the closest unique value in the array to the original one in question. If this is correct, the quick and dirty solution could be something akin to:

```
smallestDifference = 99999999 #Make this some large number
y = array[someindex]
for thing in array:
     difference = abs(thing-y)
          if difference<smallestDifference & difference != 0:  #Must be closer than the last recorded closest point, AND non-zero i.e. a unique point
               smallestDifference = difference #New smallest distance between points
               closestPoint = thing #Record the new closest point
print(f"x = {closestPoint}, |y-x| = {smallestDifference}")
```

Might be a bit trickier if this a >1d array and probably not the fastest solution since it has to check every point .. but probably would get the job done :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should have specified in the OP, my data is all 2D (they represent a location via a coordinate pair).

Comment: @CBBAM Oh okay! So it's an array of 2d x/y points, and you're wanting to find the closest point in that array to a known point in the same array?

Comment: Yeah kind of, I have a point x which may or may not be in the array. I want to find the point y in the array such that it is closest to x but also not x itself.

Comment: Posted it as an edit to this answer -- let me know if anything doesn't seem quite right, cheers!